# How many times jeeva gets human birth?

Tags: atma, death, rebirth, human

As per Hinduism we get 84 lakh yoni time birth on this earth. So how many times we get birth as human being ? is it true that we get human birth only once out of 84 lakh yoni ?
Please let me know If anyone knows that...

Comment: Unlimited. Realize your divinity and get out of cycle of births and deaths.

Comment: "As per Hinduism we get 84lacs yoni time birth on this earth". What scriptures say that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How difficult or rare is it to get human life?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20424/how-difficult-or-rare-is-it-to-get-human-life)

Answer (score 6):

Your question can't be definitely answered from Scriptures.Its true that the soul gets a variety of Yonis(wombs) as per its karmas and  its also true that the number of such Yonis is 84 lacs .

But we can't exactly say how many times it gets born in a particular Yoni (possibly innumerable times) .The Scriptures only emphasize the fact that a birth in a human Yoni is very very rare.So we all should be proactive and make full use of it.

> **Chaturashitilakshesu** Sarireshu SaririnAm | Na Manushyam VinA Annyatra Tatva GyAnantu Labhyate ||
>
> **Among the 84 lacs of kinds of bodies(wombs)** Tatva Gyana(Brahma Gyana,self realization) is achieved only in the human body and not in
>   any other bodies.
>
> **Kularnava Tantram,Chapter 1, Verse 14.**
>
> SopAnabhutam Mokshasya MAnushyam PrApya Durlabham | YastArayati
>   NAtmAnam TasmAth PApatarohatra ||
>
> Who is more sinner than the one who does not make full use of the
>   human birth, which is rare(durlabham) and which is like a staircase to moksha(liberation).
>
> **KulArnava Tantram 1-16.**