# Do all species have soul?

Tags: animals, science, human, plants

There is a famous quote which is circulating online that according to Hinduism, soul transmigrates through 8.4 million or 84 lakh bodies before reaching human form. Now, if we remove 4 lakh human species from the quote, only 80 lakh species are available. But [science says](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how%20many%20species&oq=how%20&aqs=chrome.4.69i59j69i60j69i59j69i61j69i59j69i57.2940j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) 87 million species are discovered, and still 80% of the world species are not discovered. So, as only places in India are mentioned in Hindu epics, only Indian species have souls or the other way around?

Comment: In one word answer is Yes! All species have souls.

Comment: @Just_Do_It all species living in the world?

Comment: Yes all species living anywhere.

Comment: @Just_Do_It Then why only 8 million mentioned?

Comment: 'famous quote' - from where?? Anecdotes are not references.

Comment: @Swami Vishwananda people say it is mentioned in Padma Purana. I actually wanted to quote the verse here but somehow I forgot.

Comment: @NarayanaSharma It is from Vishnu Purana but why are you linking Science with it?

Comment: @TheDestroyer I am actually saying there are more than 8 million species discovered.

Comment: @NarayanaSharma It will be better if we don't mix Science with Scriptures. Science evolves gradually and it will be better if we limit questions to Hinduism only.

Comment: @TheDestroyer This question is actually limited to Hinduism only. If I removed the discovery of more than 8 million species, my question will become pointless.

Comment: You may be interested in [no. of Jivas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8443/277)

Comment: read the difference between Atman Vs soul from "Being Different" by Rajiv Malhotra. All being are reflection of the Paramathama i.e. they have atman ... Soul is more of a "abhrahamic" concept which only humans have Atman (Dharmic) != Soul (Abrahamic) Even Amoeba has a "soul"

Comment: It's 84 lakhs of Yonis/wombs .. It's mentioned in my answer here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17705/how-many-times-jeeva-gets-human-birth @NarayanaSharma